# Problems installing Joomla plugins

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have a J2.5 install that simply refuses to install plugins using the extensions manager.

The directories are all writable, the Forum Post Assistant reports that session is writable, tmp path is ok, and the relevant directories have been made chmod777, and all files on the server have the same owner. Yet I still receive the following error when I try to install

```
JFTP: :mkdir: Bad response
JFTP: :chmod: Bad response
Component Install: Failed to create site directory: path.to/components/com_neorecruit
```

If I manually create the com_neorecruit directory then I receive the following error.

```
JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: path.to/administrator/components/com_neorecruit
JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: path.to/administrator/components/com_neorecruit
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file
JFTP: :mkdir: Bad response
JFTP: :chmod: Bad response
Component Update: Failed to create admin directory:path.to/administrator/components/com_neorecruit
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have folder/file ownership? Best check with your host to see if you do as this might be an issue

Comment: Hi @Lodder All files have the same owner and it appears to be the correct owner

Comment: Have a look at this: http://vel.joomla.org/articles/234-ftp-layer.html

Comment: @Lodder already tried FTP, no dice.

Comment: Have you tried logging to FTP account manually?

Answer (score 0):

All this turned out to be down to an incorrectly set ftp root, which was pointing at `/` rather than `/htdocs`.